# Wordpress Insert manually heatmap code

Tags: wordpress, heatmap

We have a theme developed on Genesis Framework. We need install manually the heatmap code (luckyorange). I asume that the file is similar to footer.php but i could find this file.

I would appreciate any suggestion

Regards

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: This question is about wodpress i don´t see involved on this question Hardware and software relationship